# Ajax error/success messages from multiple pages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Looking to use Ajax for error messages using an associative PHP array.

I have 5 pages which have a variety of different error messages, however they all stem from the same page (It's a profile page, with 5 pages to edit different aspects of customer details).

So if there is an error, it will redirect back to a central page, and then the error will be shown using jQuery, the same with the success messages.

So my array would look like:

```
 $errormsg = array("class"=>"warning", "message"=>"Example error message");
```

However, I have read tutorials and have seen examples like the following:

```
jQuery.ajax({

url: 'script.php',
data: response,
dataType: 'JSON',
type: 'POST',
success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
},
error: function(data, errorThrown){
    console.log(errorThrown);
}

});
```

How do I go about specifying 5 different URL's for example? As I would want to avoid having this code duplicated 5 times for one page, as well as many other times accross my site.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Save the object you pass into `jQuery.ajax` to a variable. Then you can change `objVar.url = "whatever.php";` and just pass that into the ajax call like `jQuery.ajax(objVar);`. It is just a standard javascript object literal you pass into ajax. It can be saved/modified just like any other object.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean.

I have several pages that all use the same AJAX "processor page" (for want of a better term). Here is how I handle it:

```
var req = 'page1';
var error_type = $('#etype').val();
var error_somethingelse = 'this is something else';
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
     url: 'ajax/ax.php',
    data: {request:req, error_type:etype, sumelse:error_somethingelse},
    success: function(d){
        if (d.length) alert(d);
    }
});
```

The `request` variable tells the PHP ajax processor file which routine to run:

**ax.php:**

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['request'] == '') {

    /**********************************************************************************************************************/ 
    }else if ($_POST['request'] == 'page1') {
        if ($_POST['page1_specific_var']== '123-324'){
        }
        echo 'Error Message: there was an error';
    }else if ($_POST['request'] == 'page2') {
        echo 'Error Message: there was another kind of error';
    }else if ($_POST['request'] == 'login_page') {
        echo 'Error Message: there was a login error';
    }
```